# Error access two datasource with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I'm developing an APP that accesses two bases: Db2 and SQL Server with spring boot.

When I try to access the second datasource the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

It is not a problem with the driver because when I squeeze the app to run with just one of the banks it works

Follow below how the project is:

**application.properties:**

```
Conexao sqlserver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;DatabaseName=DataBaseTest
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Conexao db2
spring.secondDatasource.url=jdbc:db2://localhost/DataBaseTest:user=user;password=user
spring.secondDatasource.url.driverClassName = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Multi database configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MultipleDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.secondDatasource")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean(name="dataSourceFromSQLServer")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource  dataSourceFromSqlServer() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }


    @Bean(name="dataSourceFromDb2")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.secondDatasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource secondDataSource() {
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

Class of reader

```
    public class Reader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<BaixaProtesto> {


        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        private MultipleDataSourceConfiguration multipleDataSourceConfiguration;


        public Reader(DataSource dataSource) {
          //Read base from first datasource
          //everything ok at this point
          //omitted code  
        }


        private BigDecimal getCnpjFromDB2(String name,
                                          int number) {
            //Query ommitted
            final String QUERY = "SELECT ";
            multipleDataSourceConfiguration = new MultipleDataSourceConfiguration();

            //point where the exception is thrown
            HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = multipleDataSourceConfiguration.secondDataSource();
            jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(hikariDataSource);
            return new BigDecimal("0.1");

        }
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this error? Thanks for listening

Comment: Your Spring *app* can certainly have multiple data sources, but I'm not sure they can both coexist in the same place.  Look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases.  Note "*the two entities are also placed in independent packages – this will be important as we move into the configuration...*".

Comment: Do you have *.jar driver for SQL server and DB2 in project? (https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/spring-with-db2-via-jpa/#add-db2jcc4-jar-to-the-project)

Comment: Do you have this code in git? I can try to reproduce the issue.