# Using two datasources with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I followed the docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-two-datasources and created my source code accordingly.
When I start up the application I receive this error message:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url
>
> Action: Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2,
>   HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database
>   settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to
>   activate it (no profiles are currently active).

I searched for similar issues and only found that one:
[Error access two datasource with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795090/error-access-two-datasource-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this was contained in the error message but (at least for me) a little bit too hidden.

I forgot to add the h2 jar so the real reason wasn't that Spring Boot couldn't `determine suitable jdbc url` but more the missing driver.